# Passing Data to List

Tags: ios, swiftui

What could be the issue with this code?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
let usersData = [User.init(name_: "shauket", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 30), User.init(name_: "Adil", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 24), User.init(name_: "Arslan", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 28), User.init(name_: "Ahmed", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 30), ]

var body: some View {
    List(usersData) { user in
        // here i can not access user
    }
  }
}

struct User {
var name: String
var profession: String
var age: Float
init(name_: String, profession_: String, age_: Float ) {
    self.name = name_
    self.profession = profession_
    self.age = age_
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usersData should be an identifiable array. That is, an array that contains elements that conform to the Identifiable protocol. For a type to conform to Identifiable, you basically need to have a property named id.

Alternatively, if you have another property that can uniquely identify your element, you can use it with the identified(by:) method (beta 3), or List(_:id:) (beta 4). In your case, if we use name as the unique identifier, you can do:

***Note: As of this time, Xcode beta 4 has not been released yet. But the release notes of Catalina beta 4, indicate .identified(by:) will be deprecated by List(_:id:). I include the syntax as it will presumably be, but I have no way of testing at this time.***

```swift
        // Beta 3 syntax
        List(usersData.identified(by: \.name)) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }

        // Beta 4 syntax
        List(usersData, id: \.name) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }
```

In the case that you are not able to generate an identifiable array, you may access it by index:

```swift
        List(0..<usersData.count) { i in
            Text(self.usersData[i].name)
        }
```

And if you prefer to make your `User` identifiable, you would do something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    let usersData = [User.init(id: 0, name_: "shauket", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 30), User.init(id: 1, name_: "Adil", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 24), User.init(id: 2, name_: "Arslan", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 28), User.init(id: 3, name_: "Ahmed", profession_: "Software Engineer", age_: 30), ]

    var body: some View {
        List(usersData) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var profession: String
    var age: Float
    init(id: Int, name_: String, profession_: String, age_: Float ) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name_
        self.profession = profession_
        self.age = age_
    }
}
```

***In any case, make sure that the property you use to identify your element is really unique. Otherwise, your List may produce weird results.***

Comment: I prefer to use 2nd option, id is unique but still getting same error.

Comment: My XCode got made, just restart and error gone. thanks

Comment: We are beta victims ;-) Cheers.

Comment: It seems `.identified(by:)` will be deprecated in beta 4, I updated my answer to show the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the SwiftUI [Tutorials : Make the List Dynamic / Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#make-the-list-dynamic), you should implement the protocol `Hashable, Codable, Identifiable` in your `User` struct.

> Step 3
>
> Switch to Landmark.swift and declare conformance to the Identifiable protocol.
>
> Since the Landmark type already has the id property required by Identifiable->protocol, there’s no more work to do.

Step 1

```
List(usersData.identified(by: \.name_)) { user in

}
```

Comment: Did you try to restart the Xcode before after do the changes ?